# Many-to-Many relation fields with WTForms-Alchemy?

Tags: python, flask, many-to-many, wtforms

On the [documentation page](https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relationships.html), there are examples of how to use WTForms-Alchemy with One-to-One and One-to-Many relations. I have tables that use Many-to-Many and I can't seem to figure out how to render those form fields. My code is below for reference.

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import Form as Form2
from wtforms_alchemy import model_form_factory, ModelForm, ModelFieldList
from wtforms.fields import FormField
from app.models.bookmodel import Book
from app.models.submodels import BookTypeForm

BaseModelForm = model_form_factory(Form)
BaseSubModelForm = model_form_factory(Form2)

class ModelForm(BaseModelForm):
    @classmethod
    def get_session(self):
        return db.session

class SubModelForm(BaseSubModelForm):
    @classmethod
    def get_session(self):
        return db.session

class BookTypeForm(SubModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookType
        only = ['name']

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

    book_type = ModelFieldList(FormField(BookTypeForm))
```

This is the the book_type field and model

```
class BookType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book_type'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(
        ChoiceType(BOOK_TYPES, impl=db.Unicode(16))
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<BookType (name='%s')>" % self.name
```

Comment: What do you expect to render in a many-to-many field?

Comment: I expect my select dropdown to appear as designated in my model (which I forgot to add). The model has been added for clarification. Note that I am using WTForms-Alchemy.